# I've completed the code however I don't understand what's wrong

Tags: python

Question is: *Use procedure with parameter. Ask the user to input numbers until they say “no”.  Output if each number is greater than or less than or equal to 5.*

```
def output(number):
    if number > 5:
        print("Greater than 5")
    elif number < 5:
        print("Less than 5")
    else:
        print("It is equal to 5")
userInput = "yes"
print(userInput.lower() != "no")
num = input("Enter a number \n")
output(userInput)
userInput = input("Would you like to try again?")
```

[image: syntax error image here]

Comment: `input("Enter a number \n")` --> `returns str` use `int(input())`

Comment: **We don't allow images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow.** You should post all code and errors as ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) text. Read more [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Questions with images of text/code/errors are routinely closed. Please also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the question guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure your future questions are suitable for this Q&A.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're trying to compare a str with an int. The following will fix it:

```
def output(number):
    if number > 5:
        print("Greater than 5")
    elif number < 5:
        print("Less than 5")
    else:
        print("It is equal to 5")
userInput = "yes"
print(userInput.lower() != "no")
num = int(input("Enter a number \n"))
output(userInput)
userInput = input("Would you like to try again?")
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but how it is different from the comment?

Comment: @Pygirl this is an answer instead of a comment ;)

Comment: @Dschoni lol yeah but it conveys the same as the comment.

Comment: It does convey the same message - credit to @Pygirl - you should write answers when you have the answer! :D

Comment: With something as trivial as this, I wouldn't really consider it to be worthwhile of an answer when it can easily be solved in a comment as done by @Pygirl - then it becomes less of a help to OP and more a hunt for internet points

Comment: How can an answer **including OP's code, albeit corrected** (which btw has been marked as the answer by OP) possibly be less of a help for OP? :S

Comment: I miss the part with the loop until they input `no`.